# Something like translit.net but on autohotkey

Tags: c#, c, autohotkey, transliteration

I want to write [Translit.net](http://translit.net) but on autohotkey. So I succesfully done with the part where I have only one letter:

```
:*:a::а

:*:b::б

:*:v::в

:*:g::г

:*:d::д
```

...

But now I have a problem with the translation of "shh" to "щ" and other 'two to one' char translations. When I start typing shh i get схх back, but I want to get щ. What could I do?

My current idea: When I press a key it should write down the letter and add non translated letter to a 3 element array and check if the array elements create a *shh* ,*ch*, *sh* or any other combination larger than one. Then I could remove the last 3 or 2 typed letter and send a russian letter what I need. Maybe someone know an easier way to do that. I want my script to work exactly like that page I posted. A solution in C or C# instead of AutoHotkey would help me too.

Comment: Proper implementation would implement IME (which seem to be already done more than once - https://www.bing.com/search?q=ime+translit). If you want to do it yourself you need to show code that you want help with and exact problem you trying to address (especially since based on your description you already have code working - "what is better approach" is rarely ok question on SO unless one starts with really awful approach which does not seem to be your case)

Comment: This is the full code
#SingleInstance force
//This part don't work
:*:shh::щ
:*:ja::я
:*:ju::ю
:*:je::э
:*:ch::ч
:*:zh::ж
:*:jo::ё

This part work how i want
:*:a::а
:*:b::б
:*:v::в
:*:g::г
:*:d::д
:*:e::е
:*:z::з
:*:i::и
:*:j::й
:*:k::к
:*:l::л
:*:m::м
:*:n::н
:*:o::о
:*:p::п
:*:r::р
:*:s::с
:*:t::т
:*:u::у
:*:f::ф
:*:h::х
:*:c::ц
:*:y::ы
:*:'::ь

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, while using the unicode version of Autohotkey, but only if the file is saved in UTF-8 without BOM format.

Saving the file as UNICODE (UCS-2, must be Little Endian) solves the problem.

It also works with UTF-8 with BOM, so apparently autohotkey has truble determining endianness on its own.

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. If you have a working similar code please write it. Thank you

Comment: @nKlar I didn't. I took your code and it worked under those conditions listed in the answer. Did you understand the answer?